# How do I run a function on a Result or default to a value?

Tags: rust, idioms, map-function

We wish to run a function on a `Result` or if the result is actually an error have a default value.  Something like:

```
let is_dir = entry.file_type().is_dir() || false
//                 ^--- file_type() returns a Result
//                                         ^--- default to false if Result is an IOError
```

At the moment, we're doing it with:

```
let is_dir = entry.file_type().map(|t| t.is_dir()).unwrap_or(false);
```

But that seems horribly confusing, to run a `map` on a single item result.  Is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be more familiar and comfortable with the `map` function from its common use in `Iterator`s but using `map` to work with `Result`s and `Option`s is also considered idiomatic in Rust. If you'd like to make your code more concise you can use [`map_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map_or) like so:

```rust
let is_dir = entry.file_type().map_or(false, |t| t.is_dir());
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if you find the `map` unclear, you could use an `if` or `match` to be more explicit (and verbose):

```
let is_dir = if let Ok(file_type) = entry.file_type() {
    file_type.is_dir()
} else {
    false
};
```

or

```
let is_dir = match entry.file_type() {
    Ok(file_type) => file_type.is_dir(),
    _ => false,
};
```

Not necessarily better or worse, but an option available to you :)